# Get allocation status of a file's range in an FS which supports delayed allocation

Tags: linux, filesystems

For a very large file with delayed-allocation, some sectors may have been allocated and some may not. Delayed allocation is supported by ext4/xfs/etc..

For example, create an empty file and set to very large size using fallocate(). Now the file's size could be GBs, but using `du` you will get a zero disk usage.
After some random writes, I want to get whether a specific sector/page of this file has been allocated.

Some related system calls such as mincore/fincore work on vm status of page cache. However they don't serve on-disk allocation information.
I wonder is there any method to do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the on-disk mapping of a file with the [`FIEMAP` ioctl](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/fiemap.txt). There is also the `FIBMAP` ioctl, which does a similar thing, requires root, and isn't well-documented.

Without writing C, you can use `filefrag -v` or `hdparm --fibmap` to get at the data.